# How can I do not use constructor in MainActivity in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm a beginner.
I'm trying to make Locale project with Android Studio.
So I made a class regard with Context.
In MainActivity required a constructor.
But, I'm heard that MainActivity do not need constructor but onCreate.

Here is my code.

BaseContextWrapper

```
    public class BaseContextWrapper extends AppCompatActivity {
    //AppCompatActivity-FragmentActivity-ComponentActivity-Activity-ContextThemeWrapper-ContextWrapper-Context
    public BaseContextWrapper(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @NonNull
    public static ContextWrapper wrap(Context context) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration newConfig = new Configuration();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        newConfig.setToDefaults();

        newConfig.densityDpi = metrics.densityDpi;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            context = context.createConfigurationContext(newConfig);
        } else {
            resources.updateConfiguration(newConfig, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return new BaseContextWrapper(context);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends BaseContextWrapper {
    public MainActivity(Context base) {
        super(base);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

[image: warning image]

Comment: You're not going to change how Java works. How about clicking onto "Create constructor matching super"? And this all is pointless with a GUI, because the `BaseContextWrapper` is a `Context` without a theme.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Sadly.. I already click that. And the result is my codes!.. Humm Okay.. Thanks.. I will try to rewrite with diffrent ways my code.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you inherit from. If from "extends Base ContextWrapper", then the constructor is required, it is included in the class. But if from "extends AppCompatActivity" then nothing but the onCreate() method is needed

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I have to extend BaseContextWrapper. BaseContextWrapper extends AppCompatActivity. Isn't it possible to use onCreate() method ? (And.. I'm sorry for my bad english skill.)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `MainActivity` as

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```